# Como instalar o pacote KriSp no R?

Tags: r

Quero instalar o seguinte pacote no R http://user.math.uzh.ch/furrer/software/KriSp/

Ele esta em formato tar.gz

Utilizei o seguinte comando:

> install.packages("~/KriSp_0.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Quando tento instalá-lo aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Aviso: invalid package
>
> Erro: ERROR: no packages specified
>
> Warning in install.packages

Comment: Coloque o comando que você usou antes de dar essa mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 1):

Para instalar esse pacote o jeito mais fácil é usando o `devtools`.

Instale o `devtools` usando `install.packages("devtools")`. No Windows, o devtools também pede a instalação do `RTools` que não é um pacote e sim um outro programa: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

O KriSp parece ter sido feito em versões anteriores do `R` e não possui um arquivo NAMESPACE em seu código fonte. Por isso, é necessário descompactar o código, e adicionar esse arquivo na pasta. Eu descompactei usando o 7zip e depois criei uma cópia do arquivo DESCRIPTION, mudei o nome para NAMESPACE e apaguei o conteúdo.

Em seguida usando o comando:

```
devtools::install_local("caminho para a pasta com o codigo fonte")
```

Exemplo:

```
devtools::install_local("C:/Users/daniel/Desktop/KriSp_0.4.tar/KriSp_0.4/KriSp/")
```

Você deve conseguir instalar o pacote.

Comment: Daniel, descompactei o arquivo, fiz uma copia do arquivo DESCRIPTION, mudando o nome para NAMESPACE, porém não compreendi esse ultimo passo de apagar o conteúdo?

Comment: é só abrir o arquivo com o bloco de notas, apagar tudo que está escrito e depois salvar!

Comment: Fiz exatamente o que falou, porém diz não ser um pacote do R, pois não tem descrição.

Comment: Como você está colocando o caminho da pasta?

Comment: Assim: devtools::install_local("D:/Users/Andre/Documents/KriSp_0.4.tar/KriSp_0.4/KriSp")

Comment: +1 pelo devtools, que é um excelente pacote

Comment: Um adendo: O devtools precisa do RTools apenas para fazer o build de pacotes, mas para funções mais básicas como o `install_github` não há necessidade de instalar o RTools .

Comment: Molx, quando você instala um pacote pelo código fonte o devtools faz o build na sua máquina, por isso é necessário ter o Rtools. Talvez quando o pacote é puro R, não seja necessário, mas se o pacote tiver códigos em C, por exemplo, o RTools será necessário.

Comment: Andre, é difícil descobrir o problema daqui :( Esse erro que está aparecendo parece estar relacionado ao arquivo DESCRIPTION. Veja se ele está idêntico a quando você descompactou o pacote.

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta alternativa à do Daniel, sem utilizar o `devtools`.

Primeiro você tem que instalar as dependências do pacote (os outros pacotes dos quais o `KriSp` depende):

```
install.packages(c("fields","SparseM"), repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
```

Depois você baixa o arquivo e manda instalar como tipo `"source"` pois ele não está no formato binário:

```
install.packages("KriSp_0.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Entretanto, como o Daniel disse, como este pacote foi feito numa época em que não havia NAMESPACE, se você tentar isso em versões recentes do R terá problemas.

[O NAMESPACE, grosso modo, diz que funções você vai exportar para o usuário no ambiente global, que funções você não vai exportar, que pacotes ou funções de outros pacotes você vai importar etc](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces). Então você pode fazer o seguinte: descompactar a pasta KriSp de dentro do tar e criar nela um arquivo de texto simples chamado NAMESPACE com o seguinte conteúdo.

```
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

Você está basicamente mandando exportar todas as funções que não começam com ponto. Agora é só mandar instalar pelo "source" novamente, mas dessa vez colocando o nome da pasta e não o nome do tar.

```
install.packages("KriSp", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Acabei de testar aqui e funcionou. Todavia, só porque instalou não quer dizer que está ok, então vale a ressalva de que este pacote pode estar cheio de problemas de compatibilidade, uma vez que não tem manutenção há muito tempo.

Comment: Carlos, essa primeira parte eu fiz, porém como disse esse pacote é muito antigo, nessa nova versão do R acredito que não instala

Comment: @andre com os comandos que listei instala, pois acabei de instalar aqui.

Comment: Carlos poderia mandar para mim sua pasta do KriSp?

Comment: @andre blz, mais tarde coloco no dropbox e passo o link

Comment: Faz essa gentileza Carlos, não consigo instalar.

Comment: @andre segue o link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44201187/KriSp.zip

Comment: Carlos, tem certeza que conseguiu instalar o pacote?

Comment: sim, @andre, tenho certeza

Comment: Qual versão do seu R? Cara não instala no meu.